# Error when reading a fetched array in PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code

```php
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

$query = "SELECT meta.post_id post_id, post.post_content content, count(1) cont
FROM postmeta meta
LEFT JOIN posts post ON meta.post_id = post.id
WHERE meta_value in ($value)
GROUP BY meta.post_id ORDER BY cont DESC";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
var_dump($result);

$result->data_seek(0);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r($row);
```

And when I want to print the $row variable, it send a Server Internal Error, but if I remove this line it works fine. The problem is, I can not get the information from the $result variable.

Any ideas about this?

Comment: Tell us about $value

Comment: $value has a string with string values separated with coma like "'hi', 'please'"

Comment: How about: `foreach ($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
{
    print_r($row);
}`